# Send Image Using ACTION.SEND android

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I have Files in Asset folder , how can i send them using ACTION.SEND intent to Gmail or Other apps exept Facebook (i know how to use JSON)?
i am using this code but it does not work, i have tried so many things , even Attaching File to GMAIL is successful but when sending it , nothing will be post to Gmail account!

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", body);
 sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///android_assets/T1.png");
 sendIntent.setType("image/png");
 startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"test@test.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<b>Bold message body</b>"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:/sdcard/test.txt"));
emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email"));
```

Comment: ARE U SURE U READ MY QUESTION??? what is the difference Between your answer and what i asked?????? just changing senintent to emailintent?? u kidding

Comment: 1)emailIntent.setType(**"application/octet-stream"**); 2)Uri.parse(**"file:/sdcard/test.txt"**) I read file from SD card instead of assets folder.