# Can't send HTML file as attachment of a mail, neither from internal nor external storage

Tags: android, email, android-intent, storage, attachment

I've been reading in SO that it is (surprisingly) impossible to send a file as mail attachment which is on internal storage (even in MODE_WORLD_READABLE).

Therefore, I'm using a (dirty) code that copies the file to the external storage before sending the mail.

The problem is, when I receive the mail, the attachment isn't there (although it was displayed as attachment when sending it)!

Yet, when I manually send the file via mail using Root Explorer, everything works perfectly...

Here's my code:

```
File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = getDir("MyApp", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
copyFile(new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+Ref+"-"+Name+".html"), new File(sdDir+File.separator+Ref+"-"+Name+".html"));
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailtext);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(sdDir+File.separator+ReservationReference+"-"+LastName+".html")); //"file://"+dir.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+ReservationReference+"-"+LastName+".html"));
this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send by mail"));
```

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553083/send-image-using-action-send-android/13553333#13553333).

Comment: Tried already, mail is very ugly, no colors, no tables...etc.